# Created jar from JRuby file using warbler. Application exit/goes in a blink when run

Tags: jruby, desktop-application, warbler

I have created a JRuby desktop application. [Now I need to create installation file for different platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223998/how-to-create-distribution-files-exe-with-jruby)(Windows, Linux, Mac).

I have created .jar file [using warbler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269164/create-deployable-jruby-jar-file). But when I try to run the .jar, application starts and exit in a blink. It seems application is not crashing as the log says got via `java -jar MyApp.jar > log.txt`.

Why the application exit, doesn't just stay. Can somebody help me on what I am missing. How I can track the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will help for the issue: [JRuby script with Rubeus and Swing exiting once packaged into jar using warble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108822/jruby-script-with-rubeus-and-swing-exiting-once-packaged-into-jar-using-warble)

The workaround described is to put below code in your App's main file

```
event_thread = nil
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait { event_thread = java.lang.Thread.currentThread }
event_thread.join
```